# Why does NAT not work for all hosts in subnet?

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, nat, xen

Network noob here. I am creating an emulated network for malware analysis. This means, I need to have one "real" host (VM) that is connected to the emulated network.

My setup so far consists of a Xen host with two VMs. One is the malware analysis VM (**windom**) and the other is a mininet VM (**mininetdom**). On the second a mininet network is running. I connected this VM with 3 bridge devices to the admin domain (**dom0**). One of these (**emubr**) is only used to connect the analysis VM to the emulated mininet network. A second (**natbr**) is used to connect the emulated network (and the analysis VM) to the internet via NAT on the admin domain. I created NATing with the lines in `/etc/ufw/before.rules` and enabled ufw:

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o ens33 -j MASQUERADE

COMMIT
```

And `iptables -t nat -L -v` gives the following:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 120 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    2   120 DOCKER     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 120 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 8 packets, 594 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  any    any     anywhere            !localhost/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 3 packets, 232 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere            
    8   580 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    ens33   anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  docker0 any     anywhere             anywhere
```

And for `iptables -t nat -S`:

```
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o ens33 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
```

The third (**hobr**) bridge is only used for SSH connection. The router **R** connects three subnets (10.0.0.0/24 -- 3 hosts + analysis vm; 10.0.1.0/24 -- 3 hosts; 10.0.2.0/24 -- 3 hosts) and he routes traffic not belonging to any connected subnet to eth1 (and to the internet in the long run).

Basic network image for overview:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOM4C.png

Now what works is:

- Ping inside the emulated network (any host <-> host)
- Ping from analysis vm to the emulated network (any host)
- Ping internet from emulated network to internet. For this to work, I had to add entries in the routing table of dom0 to the subnets (`{10.0.0.0/24, 10.0.2.0/24, 10.0.2.0/24} via 10.0.3.2 dev natbr`)

What's not working is:

- Ping internet from analysis vm

**Problem identification**
I narrowed the problem down to a improper working NAT on dom0. The ping coming from the analysis vm is traversing emubr to eth2. The router is routing the request correctly to eth1. With tcpdump I can see the packet coming in at natbr on dom0. But it does not change the src ip address when I analyse it on the eth0 (on dom0) interface. This is different, if I ping the internet from say 10.0.1.12 (a host in the emulated network).

If I connect the windom vm to the natbr directly, everything works properly. So it should not be a problem with this host.

How could I identify, why NATing works on the emulated hosts, but not on the analysis vm (which should be equal to one of the emulated hosts)? I cannot identify any problems in the packets coming out of natbr, that could cause a problem in the NATing.

Comment: Please show the iptables rules in `-t nat -L -v` or even `-t nat -S` format. The default `-L` output omits important fields such as the interface names.

Comment: Thank you. Have updated the post.